# Rails 3: Actionmailer :BCC field doesn't work

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

The :bcc field doesn't seem to work.

```
 mail(:to => "xx@xxx.org",
       :bcc => "xx1@xxx.org",
       :subject => "Welcome to My Awesome Site")
```

I want to pass to the :BCC field an array of 100 e-mails to send but this doesn't work even when I pass only 1 value.

Thanks

Comment: Ditto - Ruby 1.9.2p290, rails 3.0.10.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How To Send E-Mails With BCC in Rails 3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6576316/how-to-send-e-mails-with-bcc-in-rails-3)

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into this as well. However, I  narrowed it down to my use of SES for delivery. I found this issue 
https://github.com/drewblas/aws-ses/issues/16

When I used sendmail, the bcc worked just fine.