# How To Send E-Mails With BCC in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, actionmailer

How can I send e-mails with the BCC header? I follow the ruby on rails guide and set `:bcc => "email@email.com"` and it doesn't work.

Thanks

*edit by corroded*
Here's the code I tried:

```
def booking_confirmed_email(booking)
  @booking = booking
  mail(:to => booking.contact_email,
       :bcc => "my@email.com",
       :subject => "Congratulations, #{booking.contact_name}!")
end
```

also tried:

```
def booking_confirmed_email(booking)
  @booking = booking
  mail(:to => booking.contact_email,
       :bcc => ["my@email.com"],
       :subject => "Congratulations, #{booking.contact_name}!")
end
```

to no avail

Comment: i also have the same issue, bcc just doesn't work

Comment: Are you saying it "doesnt" work because it didnt turn up in the log in development environment or you didnt receive any emails in production mode (with actual delivery)? I've seen that in development mode with no delivery, BCC doesnt get printed out in the log.

Comment: This is still not working. I'm on rails 3.1.4 and actionmailer 3.1.4. Anyone found a solution to this?

Comment: Are you using Amazon SES? Might be their issue: https://github.com/drewblas/aws-ses/issues/16

Comment: @AdityaSanghi - you brought up a very good point. I believed my `:bcc` declaration was not working because I did not see an appropriate entry in the development log. It was functioning properly, just not showing up in the log.

Comment: Hey! If you're interested, I answered this question with a blog post — https://railsnotesui.xyz/blog/rails-actionmailer-cc-bcc

Answer (score 55):

Full details here:

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionMailer/Base.html

Short answer:

```
mail(:to => "some@example.com" ,  :subject => "Example Subject",
     :bcc => ["bcc@example.com", "Order Watcher <watcher@example.com>"] ,
     :cc => "other@example.com" )
```

note how you can pass an array of email addresses to each of the :to, :cc, :bcc options.

RailsCast:

http://railscasts.com/episodes/206-action-mailer-in-rails-3

Comment: already tried array or string in :bcc field and it doesn't work. that's why i added the bounty

Comment: that's weird! it definitely works for me.. can you post the code you tried?

Comment: added the code. it's the same as yours and it sends out the email(both HTML and TEXT versions). but NO bcc.

Comment: I definitely have arrays for both :to and :bcc and it works. Could it be that one of your email addresses is malformed?  My code looks exactly like yours - just a different model name

Comment: nope, im using the email address in one of the to fields in my other action. it DOES send it, but not BCC. this is really frustrating as tehre are no error messages and it sends to the to field

Comment: Are you trying this in Production mode or Development mode? What's your ActionMailer gem version? I'm using 3.0.7 .  what does the Rails log file say? Does it still send the :to and :cc ?  If so, what does the system's mail log say? e.g. under /var/log/

Comment: I was trying it in both production and dev. both showed the emails being sent but no errors, meaning the logs show the text and html ocntent of the email but no bcc. i will check the prod logs later to see the actual message

Comment: it is normal that you don't see the BCC in the logs.. still, the message should arrive at the destination.

Comment: that's another thing, it doesn't even in production.

Comment: @corroded you might want to check the configuration of the sendmail on your system (or postfix)

Comment: I'm experiencing the same problem. Very weird. I "feel" it could be something related to using :smtp instead of local mail server...

Answer (score 4):

on your user_mailer, on your mail def, add the following:

```
mail(:subject => "enter your subject", :bcc => "email@email.com")
```

you can also make your bcc recieve a list of emails

```
@bcc = User.all.pluck(:email)
```

then call

```
mail(:subject => "enter your subject", :bcc => @bcc)
```

hope this helps. :)

Comment: `@bcc = User.all.email` won't work. Do you mean `@bcc = User.all.map(&:email)`?

Comment: User.all.pluck(:email) is more efficient

Answer (score 4):

I've just exactly the same problem.  It turns out in my case **I was BCC'ing the same address I was TO'ing**.  ActionMailer or the mail server was doing something clever and choosing to only send one copy of the email.

I changed to using two different email addresses and BCC worked perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

Check out http://railscasts.com/episodes/206-action-mailer-in-rails-3 and add 'default :bcc => "your_required_bcc_email"  in your equivalent of the user_mailer.rb

Comment: that means all your emails will have a bcc. what if you only need to add the bcc to one method?

Comment: and i just tested this and it still didnt work. im using actionmailer 3.0.7 btw

Comment: But you are able to send email via :to => ,aren't you?

Comment: yup, ive got no problems with to, but i need bcc on a specific action

Answer (score 0):

If you are using any queue adaptor (ex. Sidekiq) - try restart it.